# Como especifico el usuario de mi otro servidor para poder realizar bien la consulta SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo que generar un evento que se ejecute cada dia para obtener datos de una base de datos a otra.
Este es mi codigo pero donde pongo SERVIDOR2019\A3RP es el nombre del servidor y PRUEBAS la base de datos. No tengo que especificar con que usuario me conecto o algo por el estilo.

```
BEGIN

DELETE FROM VLD__ALERGIAS

SELECT * INTO VLD__ALERGIAS 
FROM
SERVIDOR2019\A3ERP.PRUEBAS.VLD__ALERGIAS

DELETE FROM VLD__USUARIOS

SELECT * INTO VLD__USUARIOS 
FROM
SERVIDOR2019\A3ERP.PRUEBAS.VLD__USUARIOS

DELETE FROM VLD__ALERGIAS_USER

SELECT * INTO VLD__ALERGIAS_USER 
FROM
SERVIDOR2019\A3ERP.PRUEBAS.VLD__ALERGIAS_USER

DELETE FROM VLD__CENTROS

SELECT * INTO VLD__CENTROS 
FROM
SERVIDOR2019\A3ERP.PRUEBAS.VLD__CENTROS

DELETE FROM ARTICULO

SELECT * INTO ARTICULO 
FROM
SERVIDOR2019\A3ERP.PRUEBAS.ARTICULO

DELETE FROM VLD_ _ARTICULOSUSUARIO

SELECT * INTO VLD__ARTICULOSUSUARIO 
FROM
SERVIDOR2019\A3ERP.PRUEBAS.VLD__ARTICULOSUSUARIO

DELETE FROM VLD__ROL

SELECT * INTO VLD__ROL 
FROM
SERVIDOR2019\A3ERP.PRUEBAS.VLD__ROL

DELETE FROM __CLIENTES

SELECT * INTO __CLIENTES 
FROM
SERVIDOR2019\A3ERP.PRUEBAS.__CLIENTES

DELETE FROM PERSONA

SELECT * INTO PERSONA 
FROM
SERVIDOR2019\A3ERP.PRUEBAS.PERSONA

DELETE FROM SERIES

SELECT * INTO SERIES 
FROM
SERVIDOR2019\A3ERP.PRUEBAS.SERIES

DELETE FROM RUTAS

SELECT * INTO RUTAS 
FROM
SERVIDOR2019\A3ERP.PRUEBAS.RUTAS

DELETE FROM VLD__CURSOS

SELECT * INTO VLD__CURSOS 
FROM
SERVIDOR2019\A3ERP.PRUEBAS.VLD__CURSOS

DELETE FROM VLD__TIPOCLIENTE

SELECT * INTO VLD__TIPOCLIENTE 
FROM
SERVIDOR2019\A3ERP.PRUEBAS.VLD__TIPOCLIENTE

DELETE FROM VLD__TIPOS

SELECT * INTO VLD__TIPOS 
FROM
SERVIDOR2019\A3ERP.PRUEBAS.VLD__TIPOS

DELETE FROM VLD__USUARIOS

SELECT * INTO VLD__USUARIOS 
FROM
SERVIDOR2019\A3ERP.PRUEBAS.VLD__USUARIOS

DELETE FROM VLD_CONTROLES_CALENDARIO

SELECT * INTO VLD_CONTROLES_CALENDARIO 
FROM
SERVIDOR2019\A3ERP.PRUEBAS.VLD_CONTROLES_CALENDARIO

DELETE FROM VLD_CONTROLES_CALENDARIO_TAREAS

SELECT * INTO VLD_CONTROLES_CALENDARIO_TAREAS 
FROM
SERVIDOR2019\A3ERP.PRUEBAS.VLD_CONTROLES_CALENDARIO_TAREAS


END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De mano las dos instancias de Sql tienen que estar accesibles en la red.

Luego puedes establecer un servidor vinculado contra la segunda instancia "SERVIDOR19\A3ERP", mediante el Sql Management Studio, o mediante TSQL.

[image: NuevaConexión]

[image: Datos Servidor]

[image: Seguridad]

[image: Salida]

Mediante TSQL.

```
USE [master]
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'VINCULADO', @srvproduct=N'', @provider=N'SQLOLEDB', @datasrc=N'SERVIDOR2019\A3RP', @catalog=N'Pruebas'

GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'VINCULADO', @optname=N'collation compatible', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'VINCULADO', @optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'VINCULADO', @optname=N'dist', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'VINCULADO', @optname=N'pub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'VINCULADO', @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'VINCULADO', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'VINCULADO', @optname=N'sub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'VINCULADO', @optname=N'connect timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'VINCULADO', @optname=N'collation name', @optvalue=null
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'VINCULADO', @optname=N'lazy schema validation', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'VINCULADO', @optname=N'query timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'VINCULADO', @optname=N'use remote collation', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'VINCULADO', @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
USE [master]
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname = N'VINCULADO', @locallogin = NULL , @useself = N'False', @rmtuser = N'UserVinculado', @rmtpassword = N'UserVinculadoPassword'
GO
```

Conexión establecida en TSQL con un login de SQL Server a la base de datos Pruebas.

Cambiar el usuario donde dice xx por lo que corresponda:
Usuario=UserVinculado
Password = UserVinculadoPassword

Ahora tú código quedaría tal que:

```
BEGIN

DELETE FROM VLD__ALERGIAS

SELECT * INTO VLD__ALERGIAS 
FROM
[VINCULADO].PRUEBAS.VLD__ALERGIAS

DELETE FROM VLD__USUARIOS

SELECT * INTO VLD__USUARIOS 
FROM
[VINCULADO].PRUEBAS.VLD__USUARIOS

DELETE FROM VLD__ALERGIAS_USER

SELECT * INTO VLD__ALERGIAS_USER 
FROM
[VINCULADO].PRUEBAS.VLD__ALERGIAS_USER

DELETE FROM VLD__CENTROS

SELECT * INTO VLD__CENTROS 
FROM
[VINCULADO].PRUEBAS.VLD__CENTROS

DELETE FROM ARTICULO

SELECT * INTO ARTICULO 
FROM
[VINCULADO].PRUEBAS.ARTICULO

DELETE FROM VLD_ _ARTICULOSUSUARIO

SELECT * INTO VLD__ARTICULOSUSUARIO 
FROM
[VINCULADO].PRUEBAS.VLD__ARTICULOSUSUARIO

DELETE FROM VLD__ROL

SELECT * INTO VLD__ROL 
FROM
[VINCULADO].PRUEBAS.VLD__ROL

DELETE FROM __CLIENTES

SELECT * INTO __CLIENTES 
FROM
[VINCULADO].PRUEBAS.__CLIENTES

DELETE FROM PERSONA

SELECT * INTO PERSONA 
FROM
[VINCULADO].PRUEBAS.PERSONA

DELETE FROM SERIES

SELECT * INTO SERIES 
FROM
[VINCULADO].PRUEBAS.SERIES

DELETE FROM RUTAS

SELECT * INTO RUTAS 
FROM
[VINCULADO].PRUEBAS.RUTAS

DELETE FROM VLD__CURSOS

SELECT * INTO VLD__CURSOS 
FROM
[VINCULADO].PRUEBAS.VLD__CURSOS

DELETE FROM VLD__TIPOCLIENTE

SELECT * INTO VLD__TIPOCLIENTE 
FROM
[VINCULADO].PRUEBAS.VLD__TIPOCLIENTE

DELETE FROM VLD__TIPOS

SELECT * INTO VLD__TIPOS 
FROM
[VINCULADO].PRUEBAS.VLD__TIPOS

DELETE FROM VLD__USUARIOS

SELECT * INTO VLD__USUARIOS 
FROM
[VINCULADO].PRUEBAS.VLD__USUARIOS

DELETE FROM VLD_CONTROLES_CALENDARIO

SELECT * INTO VLD_CONTROLES_CALENDARIO 
FROM
[VINCULADO].PRUEBAS.VLD_CONTROLES_CALENDARIO

DELETE FROM VLD_CONTROLES_CALENDARIO_TAREAS

SELECT * INTO VLD_CONTROLES_CALENDARIO_TAREAS 
FROM
[VINCULADO].PRUEBAS.VLD_CONTROLES_CALENDARIO_TAREAS

END
```

[Servidores vinculados SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Una duda el servidor tengo que vincularlo si o si no? o con el TSQL delante de mi consulta serviria, perdona pero ando un poco perdido. Esque intento vincular el servidor y me da error de establecion conexion

Comment: Quiero conectarme con el login sql no con el usuario de window

Comment: @daniellandete he modificado el código TSQL para que utilice un login Sql. Que ya existe en el servidor de destino y que tiene acceso a la base de datos pruebas. El servidor vinculado se establece con ese login a esa base de datos.